# How to count the duplicates of rows in a dataframe with multiple columns of integers

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count, duplicates

I have a question regarding to counting duplicates of rows in a dataframe. For example I have the following data frame.

```
df1 = 
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12   13   14   15
0  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2    2    2    2
1  3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3    3    3    3    3    3
2  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1    1    1    1    1
3  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1    1    1    1    1
4  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1    1    1    1    1
5  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1    1    1    1    1
6  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2    2    2    2
7  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2    2    2    2
8  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2    2    2    2
9  3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3    3    3    3    3    3
```

Is there a way to counts the duplicates and give me the following dataframe?

```
df1_duplicates =
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12   13   14   15   Count
0  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1    1    1    1    1    4
1  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2    2    2    2    4
2  3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3    3    3    3    3    3    2
```

I have tried using the following code,

```
df_duplicates = df1.groupby(df1.columns.tolist()).size().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

it does give me the count, but the output dataframe become a single column dataframe as shown below.

```
df_I_dont_want_this =
                    0 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  4
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  4
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3  3  3  3  3  3  2
```

Comment: Your case is easy because you have multiple columns of single-digit integers. (But what if it had '12' or '333'? we'd probably want to string-match `"1,12,333,..."` with comma separators). Also beware strings and whitespace, uppercase/lowercase in hex numbers '0x4ec' == '0x4EC'...

Comment: You are right, but I dont know why groupby always output a "Pandas.core.series.Series" instead of "pandas.core.frame.DataFrame"

Comment: Please give us code that generates your dataframe, not just the text output or print. (Helps make this reproducible)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. WeNYoBen solved the problem. I will provide the code next time. Thank you.

Comment: Actually you want to avoid comma as field-separator, esp. might get confused with formatted thousands separator or (European) decimal separator. So, `|` or `;` are better separators: `"1|12|333|..." is reasonably unambiguous, also visually clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want

```
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().to_frame('count').reset_index()
Out[28]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  count
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1      4
1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2   2   2   2   2   2      4
2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3   3   3   3   3   3      2
```

Comment: Can I ask one more question. Does groupby always automatically sort the dataframe to incremental order?

Comment: @TommyYip pass it `df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(),sort=False)`

Comment: It works perfectly with sort=False. Thank you so much!